# Query with more results works fine but with less results taking time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sqlperformance

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM TABLEA _tablea
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT CM_CASE_ID,
    LOG_TIMESTAMP,
    ACTION_PERFORMED_BY,
    CASE_FOLLOW_UP_DATE,
    ACTION_PICKLIST_ID,
    CASE_REQUEST_NOTE_VALUE,
    CASE_STATUS_ID,
    RESOLUTION_PICKLIST_ID,
    PREVIOUS_REQUEST_OWNER,
    CURRENT_REQUEST_OWNER,
    CASE_FOLLOW_UP_NOTE_VALUE,
    CM_PENDING_REASON_ID,
    ACCOUNT_STATUS
  FROM TABLEB _tableb
  WHERE _tableb.LOG_TIMESTAMP
    ||_tableb.CM_CASE_ID IN
    (SELECT MIN(_tableb.LOG_TIMESTAMP)
      ||_tableb.CM_CASE_ID AS col_0_0_
    FROM TABLEB _tableb
    WHERE _tableb.CASE_STATUS_ID='A'
    GROUP BY _tableb.CM_CASE_ID
    )
  ) _tableb
ON _tablea.CM_CASE_ID=_tableb.CM_CASE_ID
WHERE _tablea.CASE_CREATION_DATE BETWEEN to_date('12/01/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('06/07/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + 1
AND _tablea.CASE_REQUEST_TYPE                                                                                       IN (1,2,3)
AND _tablea.CASE_STATUS_ID                                                                                          IN ('A','B')
```

the above query which expects records between 12/01/2016 and 06/07/2017 is work fine in less time

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM TABLEA _tablea
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT CM_CASE_ID,
    LOG_TIMESTAMP,
    ACTION_PERFORMED_BY,
    CASE_FOLLOW_UP_DATE,
    ACTION_PICKLIST_ID,
    CASE_REQUEST_NOTE_VALUE,
    CASE_STATUS_ID,
    RESOLUTION_PICKLIST_ID,
    PREVIOUS_REQUEST_OWNER,
    CURRENT_REQUEST_OWNER,
    CASE_FOLLOW_UP_NOTE_VALUE,
    CM_PENDING_REASON_ID,
    ACCOUNT_STATUS
  FROM TABLEB _tableb
  WHERE _tableb.LOG_TIMESTAMP
    ||_tableb.CM_CASE_ID IN
    (SELECT MIN(_tableb.LOG_TIMESTAMP)
      ||_tableb.CM_CASE_ID AS col_0_0_
    FROM TABLEB _tableb
    WHERE _tableb.CASE_STATUS_ID='A'
    GROUP BY _tableb.CM_CASE_ID
    )
  ) _tableb
ON _tablea.CM_CASE_ID=_tableb.CM_CASE_ID
WHERE _tablea.CASE_CREATION_DATE BETWEEN to_date('05/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('06/07/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + 1
AND _tablea.CASE_REQUEST_TYPE                                                                                       IN (1,2,3)
AND _tablea.CASE_STATUS_ID   IN ('A','B')
```

this query which expects records between 05/01/2017 and 06/07/2017  is taking too much time around 20 minutes...

Pls help out why the query which expect more result working fine and less not.

Comment: Can you please post the explain plans for both queries, including some informations about the structure of the involved tables ( with indexes) and about the number of records in each table.

Answer (score 0):

you are making sql confuse. put each table as CTE Table like this : but also there is messy in where condition that should be fixed .I suggested to put every select in separate CTE and every JOIN condition in ON part and every other Condition in WHERE and avoid mix too many things .part by part select, join ,on ,where ... ,then at the end group by the result. Then just compare Execution plan for each query you will find out diffrences

```
;with cte_tablea as (
 SELECT  CM_CASE_ID, CASE_CREATION_DATE, 
 CASE_REQUEST_TYPE , CASE_STATUS_ID
  FROM TABLEA )
,cte_tableb as  (
  SELECT DISTINCT CM_CASE_ID,
  LOG_TIMESTAMP,
  ACTION_PERFORMED_BY,
  CASE_FOLLOW_UP_DATE,
  ACTION_PICKLIST_ID,
  CASE_REQUEST_NOTE_VALUE,
  CASE_STATUS_ID,
  RESOLUTION_PICKLIST_ID,
  PREVIOUS_REQUEST_OWNER,
  CURRENT_REQUEST_OWNER,
  CASE_FOLLOW_UP_NOTE_VALUE,
  CM_PENDING_REASON_ID,
  ACCOUNT_STATUS
 FROM TABLEB 
)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct
 FROM cte_tablea _tablea
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
   cte_tablea  _tableb
    on _tablea.CM_CASE_ID=_tableb.CM_CASE_ID
  WHERE _tableb.LOG_TIMESTAMP
    ||_tableb.CM_CASE_ID IN
     (SELECT MIN(_tableb.LOG_TIMESTAMP)
    ||_tableb.CM_CASE_ID AS col_0_0_
       FROM TABLEB cte_tablea
      WHERE _tableb.CASE_STATUS_ID='A'
      GROUP BY _tableb.CM_CASE_ID
    )
  and _tablea.CASE_CREATION_DATE BETWEEN to_date('05/01/2017', 
 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('06/07/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + 1
  AND _tablea.CASE_REQUEST_TYPE                                                                                       
  IN (1,2,3)
  AND _tablea.CASE_STATUS_ID   IN ('A','B')
```